# How to escape '\' from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

I am using File IO, to save a file in local system(i.e PC C: drive), URL to save is like this "C:\htmlfiles\".$name_of_file.".html" the "\" in the string "C:\htmlfiles\" is giving the problem, tell me how to escape the '\'. please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` is escaped by `\` (like all the other special chars, too), so the result would be `\\`

Comment: thanks Oezi, thanks a lot... It worked... actually i was using single quotes which was giving me logical error...

Answer (score 3):

For the pathnames you can use forward slash on Windows too
`"C:/htmlfiles/"` would work

Comment: +1 for your observation I don't know why no one gave you vote up so far